# Can I remove % from a $PATH definition in zsh?

Tags: zsh, path

issue:  ping is not found:
zsh: command not found: ping

/sbin/ping -c 3 192.168.1.114

returns the expected result

echo $PATH returns:

```
/Users/user/Scripts:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin%
```

cat ~/.zshrc returns:

```
export PATH=/Users/user/Scripts:$PATH%
```

**Will removing the % in .zshrc restore /sbin to the path?**  I am reluctant to simply try it out for fear of borking up a relative's computer.

Comment: You should also figure out why it was put in there in the first place, and fix that.

Comment: The % is of course nonsense. Since your relative owns the computer, he is the "master of the configuration", so if you change this, ask him what he intended with this odd configuration. To me, it simply looks like a typo when the .zshrc was edited. But while you are at it, you could do it properly and enclose `$PATH` between double-quotes.

Comment: Or else the user is mixing up Windows environment variables access in cmd.exe e.g. %PATH%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can remove `%` from the line with the `export` command, it shouldn't be there.

After editing it, make sure to also run

```
export PATH=/Users/user/Scripts:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

to fix it for the current shell.